# How to set date format in a connection to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, after calling the stored procedure, I can see that the time has the format `2011-05-20 19:56:09` in table.

However, in my C# program, after using an `OdbcConnection` to get the record from the table, I find that the time is in the format `05/20/2011 19:56:09`. So I manually convert the format `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss` to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` (Actually, how do I verify the format is `h` or `HH` since the hour shown is 19?).

My question is why and in which part of connection, the format is changed? How can I set invarient culture in my connection?

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand("{?=CALL stored_procedure_in_SQL(?,?)}", m_SqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("RETURN_VALUE", OdbcType.Int, 4,
    ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, false, 0, 0, null, 
    DataRowVersion.Default, null));

//@parameter1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter1", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = value1;

//@parameter2
cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter2", OdbcType.Int)=value2;

object objTime=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
Console.WriteLine(objTime.Tostring()) //05/20/2011 19:56:09
DateTime dateTime = Cdate(objTime, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"); 
//2011-05-20 19:56:09 
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")); 

//Function Cdate
static public DateTime Cdate(object val, string format)
{
    // check if the object is a date time alread
    string str;
    if(val is DateTime)
    {
        // Since val is already a dateTime,Return here
        return (DateTime)val; 
    }

    // convert via string
    if(val != DBNull.Value)
    {
        str = val.ToString().Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        str = "";
    }

    if(str == "")
    {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(str, format, 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that the value has a format in the database. [Check here for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437454/date-format-problem) on that (dealing with C# `DateTime` but the same kind of logic might be applied here).

Comment: You have too many `returns` in `CDate` method. Can you please just tell us which one is executed in your case?

Comment: @Snowbear, the first return is executed in my program, as the comment added

Comment: A `DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime` - it has **no format** - it's just a `DateTime`. What you see are **string representations** of your `DateTime` - you can chose how you want your `DateTime` to be formatted, but that's on a query-by-query basis, or as a setting in your database - it's **not** something you can set / change in your connection string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't set a `DateTime` format on a connection string.

What you are seeing are simply different formattings of a certain (internal) representation of `DateTime`.

The formatting is determined by the tools you use and for .NET code the culture your logged in with.

When you want to *display* the time, then you need to format, though when using a custom format string like you have, there are no `CultureInfo` elements involved.

Check the different [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a095fsay.aspx) overloads on `DateTime`.

Comment: +1 exactly - a `DateTime` in SQL Server is just a `DateTime` - and doesn't have a "format" associated with it.

Comment: If I understand right, since my format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, which does not correspond to any format, I do not need to worry about CultureInfo when displaying?

Comment: @Summer - I suggest reading the documentation on [custom Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). Culture _may_ have an effect, though I don't believe that in this particular case there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the dateformat in your connectionstring, but you can call `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` in the query batch.