# SQL Server 2012 DateTime format does not match to my application

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

In my SQL Server I have this date format: `dd-mm-yyyy`, and I have some dates matches to this format. But when I use a datagridview in my application, it parses as `mm-dd-yyyy` but show `dd-mm-yyyy`. So if I have `05.12.2012` in my database, it thinks that 05 is month so it shows as `12.05.2012`.

I have tried to use

```
Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
```

but it did not work.

I should change the parsing format of my application, not showing format. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the ['SET DATEFORMAT'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms189491.aspx) command to set the format of the date. However, I think you problem lies somewhere else. You should be able to access the date column as a datetime value in c#. Usually data is passed in it's native format and so you should not have problems like the one you describe.

Comment: I have already done that, I don't have any problems on SQL Server side. My problem is that my application thinks that it's gonna get a date in mm.dd.yyyy format but it gets dd.mm.yyyy format.

Comment: I thought 'SET DATEFORMAT mdy' would work. Do you use simple databinding?
However, you might consider checking this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180646/how-to-set-date-format-in-a-connection-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can also send your date in the same date format in sql from your application.

Convert your date to sql format using the culture.

This works for me as we are using different culture in one application.