# Change language in SQL Server connection string

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jdbc

I have a SQL Server in Azure, with default language eu_english. That means that the dates are in format mdy and I need them in dmy, I want to put the language to Spanish in the connection string. I have tried this. but it doesn't work:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://myazureURL:1433;DatabaseName=MyDataBase;Language=Spanish
```

I have tried adding Language=Spanish, but it doesn't work. I have also tried Language=5 because 5 is the Spanish Id of languages of my SQL Server.

I need this because I can't change default language from database settings. If I try to change default language with that:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 'Spanish';
```

It gives me this error:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 'Spanish';
```

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:
I solved it incluiding this to the connection String so in each connection it sets the language:

```
 connectionInitSqls ="SET LANGUAGE Spanish"
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @Squirrel there is no error message but the connection still with sql server language us_english and not Spanish

Comment: To me it seems you are mistaking something. [eu_english](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe#:~:text=Official%20EU%20documents%20still%20tend,YYYY%2DMM%2DDD.%22) has format yyyy-MM-dd. The format `mdy` is something you would rather find in the US. And you most probably don't even need to change the language, just properly parse the parameters, which should automatically happen if you use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: In sql server the language is eu_english and it shows dates in format mdy, if I check available languages it shows actual is eu_english and the date format is mdy it also shown in sql server .... I need to change language but if its possible without changing java code, I mean doing in the connection string or in mybatis config

Comment: You don't need to adjust the language. When saving dates, it doesn't matter in what format they are **displayed**. And you don't show any error you are getting making it a guess game on what the proper way forward is

Comment: For what I need i can´t do what you want, I need to change language of the connection, I´m using mybatis maybe that can help to change language of the connection. If I need to convert from string to date is a problem the default language because default language english, default convert is mdy and I need dmy without using format

Comment: Well, you don't really specify what you need, thus making it nearly impossible to help you. If you want good answers, you need to specify your exact problem (which is not the language) as well as what you aim for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set date format in a connection to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180646/how-to-set-date-format-in-a-connection-to-sql)

Comment: The default language is determined by the **login**. But this is likely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that is better address by changing your application code. Usually this implies a sql injection problem where you create SQL statements using string concatenation.

Comment: The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't seem to have a `Language` [connection property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver16#properties). Why do you think that would work?

Comment: The database language should be completely irrelevant. Are using parameterized queries and sending `java.util.Date` values via `DATE` JDBC type parameters? If you need to change the database language to make your code work then it sounds like you are subject to SQL Injection attacks because you're concatenating string snippets to construct SQL queries.

Comment: Likely easier to just do `SET DATEFORMAT DMY;` but it's unclear why you need this, likely you are doing SQL ijnection which is another issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the post [Change the default language of Azure SQL Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-16-how-to-change-the-default-language-of-azure/ba-p/368844) given by **@Jose Manuel Jurado Diaz**.

Currently, using stored procedures or at logging time using `T-SQL` to set the default language at the server level is not supported.

As, System messages and datetime formats are determined by the session language.

The workaround for this is to use the following command.

- To mention language in connection string you can specify this keyword [Current Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString) with the language you want ex. **`Current Language=Spanish`**
- If the connection is already established

```sql
SET LANGUAGE Spanish;
```

***Changed language from `us_english` to `Spanish` and get date format from MDY to DMY***

*Below is the sample code and output result:*

```sql
SELECT @@language;
select format(getdate(),'d');
SET Language Spanish;
SELECT @@language;
select format(getdate(),'d');
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answear i solved with something similar , i set the language on the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Some drivers dont have support to Language= or Current Language= on ConnectionString, so the solution is to execute the SQL command after the sucessfull connection, "SET LANGUAGE Spanish;"

Other solution is on SQL Server set the default language to your desired user. One way is using Management Studio, click with right button on user, choose properties and so change the Default Language to that user.