# How to display date time from c# in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, datatable

I have a class

http://pastebin.com/z5JVWCms

```
 public string Tankerler()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=se;Password=1"))
        {
            using (

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select OrderDate=Siparisler.DateScheduled,uruncikistarih=UrunTransfer.DateRealized,Siparis_Veren_Firma=Bayi.FirmName,plate=UrunTransfer.Plate,Driver=Surucu.Name,lat=TankerKonum.Lat,lng=TankerKonum.Lng,Speed=TankerKonum.Speed,Zaman=TankerKonum.ReadTime,IrsaliyeNo=UrunTransfer.PrintOutID from ProductTransfer as UrunTransfer join TransferOrder as Siparisler on Siparisler.OID=UrunTransfer.TransferOrderID Join Dealer as Bayi on Bayi.OID=Siparisler.DealerID Join Driver as Surucu on Surucu.OID=Siparisler.DriverID join devcocom_admin.TankerLocation as TankerKonum on  TankerKonum.TankerID=Siparisler.TankerID where UrunTransfer.DateRealized >DATEADD(HOUR, - 24, GETDATE()) and TankerKonum.OID in (Select MAX(TankerKonum.OID) from  devcocom_admin.TankerLocation as TankerKonum group by TankerKonum.TankerID)", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }

    }
```

I get some field from database by this class.

My javascript code

http://pastebin.com/EpPb9Yr3

```
    var markers2 = JSON.parse('<%=Tankerler() %>');


    for (i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++) {

    var data2 = markers2[i]

    title: "Plate:" + " " + " " + data2.plate+ "\n" + "Speed:" +

    " " + data2.speed+ " " + "h/km" + "\n" + "Driver: " + " " + data2.Drvier+ "\n" + 

    "Print OUT ID :" + " " + data2.prntID+" "+"OrderDate: "+data2.ordDate,
```

}

Result is like this :

Plate :34AAA34  Speed:120 h/km  Driver:John  Print OUT ID:ABC12345  OrderDate: /Date(138472560000)/

But in sql OrderDate : 2013-11-20 21:24:10.000

Comment: Please paste your code here (and properly format!) Don't make us wander off to another side.

Comment: I will assume that the column in the database is not a string but some sort of date/time type. This means that the OrderDate that you present is the value _converted into a formatted string_. It is not stored this way. There are more details in my answer to [Date Format Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437454/date-format-problem/1437466#1437466).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, some JSON serializers choose this date format. And I would *recommend* switching to one that sends proper ISO8601-formatted dates (and I would also recommend using DateTimeOffset such that the TZ is never ambiguous!), anyway ..

---

The idea is that `data2.ordDate`, which has a string value of "/Date(138472560000)/", represents `new Date(138472560000)` - or, the number of milliseconds sinch [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number).

```
// where dt is in that silly format, extract the "Unix epoch" in milliseconds
function getEpoch (dt) {
  return parseInt(dt.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
var ordDate = new Date(getEpoch(data2.ordDate))
```

And then [formatting with moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is super easy (but it's not required):

```
var str = moment(ordDate).format("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: var ordDate= data2.ordDate;
                ordDate= ordDate.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, '');
                var myDate = new Date(parseInt(ordDate)).toString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and this is how it serializes dates.
If you want to serialize them to a different format, you can try another serializer such as [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

From their website:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

Comment: +1 for Json.NET - anyway, the JavaScript `new Date(138472560000)` will evaluate to the specific Date object (or, better, using `moment.js` so that it can also be formatted nicely).